# vb transparent background with gradient

Tags: vb.net, transparency, gradient, picturebox, photoshop

I have a problem with gradients transparency key in a PictureBox in visual basic form . I want to get a good transparency as it is in the first form (in PS)
 That's what I did:

1- Drawed the picture in Adobe Photoshop (CS6) with these preset:

[image: Photoshop preset]

2- Saved the picture with this option:

[image: PNG Option]

3- Added the picture to a PictureBox in vb form with blue BackColor

[image: PictureBox with blue BackColor]

4- Changed form TransparencyKey to blue

[image: TransparencyKey]

5-The (awful) result:

[image: Result]

Comment: i feel like the problem is the fact that your image has transparency itself (the fading red and yellow) and therefor merges with the blue into a nontransparent color. not sure - but i hope it helps finding an answer.

Comment: This kind of Photoshop effect cannot work, it makes pixels partially transparent.  Which alters the background color, turning pure Blue into a shade of blue that no longer matches the color key.  So you can see it.  You need a window that supports per-pixel alpha transparency, just google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Form.TransparencyKey` property is not really what you're looking for. It will only make the parts of the image transparent that *exactly match* the color you specified (`Color.Blue`, in your case). That means that the parts of the gradient in your image that have even a remotely small amount of red or yellow in them won't match the filter.

Among the things you could try is to have your form drawn with alpha blending. Here's a [library that lets you draw stuff with transparency](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1822/Per-Pixel-Alpha-Blend-in-C), which looks like what you want.
Alternately I dug up a [walkthrough on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20758/Alpha-Blended-Windows-Forms). It involves a lot of chatting with forms interop and the OS, which might not be your cup of tea.

Note that GDI+, the system Windows Forms uses for drawing, is somewhat slow, especially when drawing images. I don't know what your project looks like, but if you're going to draw a lot of transparent images, I suggest looking towards Microsoft DirectX.